# Highcharts Data Not Showing on Ajax Call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I am working on Highcharts using PHP/MYSQL. Data is showing properly in each chart but I tried to change one chart to ajax call in order to reduce page load.
I am generating multiple series data from PHP and displaying them back in the required format but data is not showing(I alerted the data it's coming).
Below is the code of ajax call:

```js
function project_wise_lab(from_date, to_date) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'dashboard/project_wise_labtest',
    data: {
      from_dte: from_date,
      to_dte: to_date
    },
    success: function(response) {
      Highcharts.chart('subcontainer7', {

        chart: {
          type: 'line',

          height: 230,
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        title: {
          text: null
        },

        xAxis: {
          categories: ['Oct 2020', 'Nov 2020', 'Dec 2020', 'Jan 2021', 'Feb 2021', 'Mar 2021', 'Apr 2021', 'May 2021']
        },
        yAxis: {
          min: 0,
          title: {
            // text: 'Total fruit consumption'
          },
          stackLabels: {
            enabled: false,
            style: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              color: ( // theme
                Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style &&
                Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style.color
              ) || 'gray'
            }
          }
        },
        legend: {
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'bottom',
          backgroundColor: Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || 'white',
          borderColor: '#CCC',
          // borderWidth: 1,
          shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
          /* headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    */
        },
        plotOptions: {
          column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
              // enabled: true
            }
          }
        },
        colors: [
          '#4a7fbb',
          '#be4c48',
          '#97b954',
          '#7d6096'
        ],
        series: response

      });
      console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.error(xhr);
    }
  });
}
```

I have alerted the response and the data is showing in the below format:

```
{ name : 'FKI',data : [10591,10576,9309,8422,9586,11171,9327,9384] },{ name : 'FKR',data : [4740,3105,2690,3598,3686,4930,3711,3859] },{ name : 'FHR',data : [17190,12757,10837,11944,14083,15748,12544,12494] },{ name : 'FUL',data : [1308,937,1002,1086,1452,1419,1248,1362] },{ name : 'FSW',data : [9535,9102,8689,8420,9941,10915,7273,6930] },{ name : 'FWP',data : [47437,42198,43012,44979,47377,55400,46520,41682] },{ name : 'FGR',data : [2112,1366,1619,1664,2387,2355,1633,1215] }
```

**New Response after update:**

```
[{"name":"FKI","data":{"01-OCT-20":"10591","01-NOV-20":"10576","01-DEC-20":"9309","01-JAN-21":"8422","01-FEB-21":"9586","01-MAR-21":"11171","01-APR-21":"9332","01-MAY-21":"9384"}},{"name":"FKR","data":{"01-OCT-20":"4740","01-NOV-20":"3105","01-DEC-20":"2690","01-JAN-21":"3598","01-FEB-21":"3686","01-MAR-21":"4930","01-APR-21":"3711","01-MAY-21":"3859"}},{"name":"FHR","data":{"01-OCT-20":"17190","01-NOV-20":"12757","01-DEC-20":"10837","01-JAN-21":"11944","01-FEB-21":"14083","01-MAR-21":"15748","01-APR-21":"12544","01-MAY-21":"12494"}},{"name":"FUL","data":{"01-OCT-20":"1308","01-NOV-20":"937","01-DEC-20":"1002","01-JAN-21":"1086","01-FEB-21":"1452","01-MAR-21":"1419","01-APR-21":"1248","01-MAY-21":"1362"}},{"name":"FSW","data":{"01-OCT-20":"9535","01-NOV-20":"9102","01-DEC-20":"8689","01-JAN-21":"8420","01-FEB-21":"9941","01-MAR-21":"10915","01-APR-21":"7273","01-MAY-21":"6930"}},{"name":"FHP","data":{"01-OCT-20":"47437","01-NOV-20":"42198","01-DEC-20":"43012","01-JAN-21":"44979","01-FEB-21":"47377","01-MAR-21":"55400","01-APR-21":"46520","01-MAY-21":"41682"}},{"name":"FGR","data":{"01-OCT-20":"2112","01-NOV-20":"1366","01-DEC-20":"1619","01-JAN-21":"1664","01-FEB-21":"2387","01-MAR-21":"2355","01-APR-21":"1633","01-MAY-21":"1215"}}]
```

The chart is showing empty, kindly help and let me know to get the issue resolve?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: @Phil I am not using json_encode(), I made the format without using JSON. 
<code>
$text='';
   foreach ($project as $key => $value) {
      $text.="{ name : '".$key."',data : [".implode(',',$value)."] },";
   }
    $proj_json=rtrim($text,',');

     echo $proj_json; 
</code>

Comment: You should rather not create JSON “manually”. What you currently have here, is _not_ valid JSON. So jQuery will treat this as a string value. And `series: [response]` will only create an array with _one_ element, which is the full string. So, create & fill the proper _data structure_ in your PHP code, encode that as JSON and pass it back to the client, and then assign the parsed result to `series` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have two problems...

1. jQuery is interpreting your response as plain text (a string) where Highcharts expects actual JS objects
2. Your response is **not** valid JSON so you can't interpret it as such on the client-side. Rule #1 when creating JSON responses is... **never roll your own JSON**.

I recommend getting PHP to generate valid JSON and respond with the correct `Content-type`

```php
// Ensure jQuery (or any consumer) knows the response is JSON
header("Content-type: application/json");

// Create a data structure representing the series data
$data = [];
foreach ($project as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = [
        "name" => $key,
        "data" => array_values($value) // you just want the values here, not the keys
    ];
}

// Respond with JSON
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

Then in your client-side code, you can simply use

```js
series: response
```

as `response` will now be a valid JS array

---

You can also make sure jQuery treats the response as JSON by adding

```js
dataType: "json",
```

to your `$.ajax()` options but with the right `Content-type` response header, jQuery should not need this.

---

Just an FYI, `alert()` is terrible for viewing data. The best option would be to use your [browser's debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/). The second best option is to use [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

Comment: thanks for correcting but I am getting this response which seems to me is invalid, I had updated the question by pasting the JSON response.

Comment: @shani did you update the client-side code too (ie `series: response` instead of `series: [response]`). Did you also add the `header()` line like in my answer?

Comment: Yes I did update as mentioned but the format is invalid that's why not showing any data. Format needs to be the one which I mentioned in my old response

Comment: @shani ah, it was hard to tell without seeing your `$project` data. Looks like you just want the values from each `$value`. I've updated my answer

Comment: @shani sorry, it's not clear what you mean. Perhaps you should open a new question with the details